# Reading and Writing to a pre-allocated dynamic array multi-threaded without synchronization

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, synchronization, mutex

**General (Generic):**

We have a dynamic array *(Unreal Engine 4 TArray)*.
We pre-allocate it before doing any work and do not modify it's size at any point.
Is it safe to read from the array from a consumer thread, while a producer thread is writing to it, when we can guarantee that the indices read by the consumer are not overlapping with the indices modified by the producer?

**Specific (Detailed):**

We have a 2D array, implemented by two dynamic arrays *(Unreal Engine 4 TArray)*.
The outer array (X) holds pointers to it's inner arrays (Y) of type uint8 and is pre-allocated with NULLs. It's size will never change. In other words, we have an array holding array-pointers, in which the actual data is stored. When the producer thread is attempting to write data to this structure, it will only happen in this manner: The data is written to the latest existing (non-NULL) Y array. If the data should (partially) not fit into it anymore, we allocate a new Y array and pre-allocate it as well with it's maximum size (set as a constant by us). Then we update the pointer in the X array at the next unused (NULL) index to point to this new Y array, and the remaining data is written to it.

The consumer thread now wants to read data from this structure. This will be guaranteed to not be on any indices that may be modified at this point or that are not existing yet. As the producer thread is very time critical (audio thread), we want to keep it as lock-free as possible. Is this a safe procedure to do without implementing synchronization?

Comment: How many consumers and producers you have?

Comment: One consumer and one producer only.

Comment: This is not safe, 2 reasons: (1) visibility of changes to the other thread; (2) the optimized may remove redundant reads as it can prove there are no updates on the current thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing in one thread and reading in another thread you always need some synchronization. Without synchronization you get undefined behavior. In practical terms the compiler may very well notice that the data written by the writing thread isn’t read. As there is no synchronization primitive it can deduce that it also isn’t read and, this, optimize the code to elide the writing.

You *may* get away with handing off the populated array to some sort of queue with atomic operations but doing so is distinctly non-trivial and it is unlikely that you’ll get it right if you need to ask the question you asked: getting a lock-free queue implemented requires good understanding of potential data races (although it seems a singe producer/consumer queue *can* be implemented lock-free; personally I’d still stay away from it as I’m certainly not up to it).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interested in what exactly the possible compiler optimization means. Don't think I have understood this yet.

Comment: @SebastianSchon: compiler can figure out that a function merely writes data. If the destination isn’t `volatile` and if there is no synchronization primitive it means that there is no defined way to observe that the data was written. Hence the compiler can detect that the programmer surely didn’t mean to write the data and that there is better no code wasting cycles writing the data.

Comment: @RichardCritten: indeed - that was exactly negated. Should be fixed now. Thanks!